# How to center \S section in document and at header?

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

I am trying to center \S section in my document and header

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use

```
\usepackage{sectsty} \allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

I get

[image]

at header

[image]

My code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newtheorem{ex}{}
\newenvironment{ex*}
{\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}\rlap{$^*$}}\ex}
{\endex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{{\it \chaptername\,\thechapter.\  #1}}{}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\it \thesection.\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\cfoot{}
\sloppy
\usepackage{sectsty} \allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    ,unicode,bookmarksnumbered
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{GEOMETRIC PROPERTIES OF CURVES OF THE SECOND ORDER}
    \setcounter{section}{17}
\section{The Ellipse}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

How to center \S section in document and at header?

Comment: First off: don't load both `sectsty` and `titlesec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load both `sectsty` and `titlesec`, they fight each other.

If you want centered headers, tell so `fancyhdr`, using the `C` slot. I also removed the clumsy and deprecated `\fancyplain` part: the package now has `\fancypagestyle` that can redefine page styles and is simpler to use.

In order to center section titles, add `\filcenter` to the specification in `\titleformat`.

I also added a couple of options to `geometry`: `headheight` is necessary as `fancyhdr` warns you; `heightrounded` is also necessary to ensure a whole number of lines on a page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  heightrounded,% <---- IMPORTANT
  headheight=14.5pt,% <---- as asked by fancyhdr
]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  unicode,
  bookmarksnumbered,
}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newtheorem{ex}{}
\newenvironment{ex*}
  {\renewcommand\theex{\thechapter.\arabic{ex}\rlap{$^*$}}\ex}
  {\endex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\itshape Ch.\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\itshape \S\ \thesection.\ #1}}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\S\ \thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\S\ \thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{GEOMETRIC PROPERTIES OF CURVES OF THE SECOND ORDER}

\setcounter{section}{17}

\section{The Ellipse}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]